# Blank Page Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

After running Android Studio for a few minutes, the window turns blank. How can I solve this?

[image: HOW TO SOLVE THIS AFTER I RUN ANDROID STUDIO AFTER 3 to 5 MINS BECOME THIS]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

1. Close the Android Studio.
2. Go to the location where your android system Android Studio version config, there is "C:\Users(your current username).AndroidStudio..."
3. Delete the file.
4. Open your android studio again.